# What is this proper way to render nested routes directly into the main application outlet with Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I have an application with nested resources where I would not like the template outlet hierarchy to be nested: I'd like some levels to be rendered directly into the main {{ outlet }} in the application template. My solution was to do:

`renderTemplate: function() { this.render({into: 'application'}) }`

on the route I wanted to render into the main application outlet. This works, except when you try to then navigate directly to a parent resource that otherwise works; it comes up blank. I have a feeling I'm just doing this wrong, but I'm not sure of the proper way to do this.

JS fiddle here shows what I mean, try drilling down to the bottom-most level and then clicking to navigate back up (you'll get a blank page) http://jsfiddle.net/Unwyp/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment about duplicate, I reworked the fiddle slightly by making the `ninjas` template into `ninjas/index` with the corresponding controller. This fiddle works http://jsfiddle.net/qEa5H/

Comment: Thanks, this works.  It seems kind of strange but I guess it makes sense in terms of Controller hierarchy.